# Is there a way to use requests to send "multipart/form-data" without using the files parameter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, discord, multipartform-data

### Background

I have been attempting to work with the Discord API for quite some time and have hit a problem I am currently unable to solve. When attempting to upload a file, the documentation states that I should use a `multipart/form-data` to do this, giving [two examples](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#editing-message-attachments-example-request-bodies-multipartformdata). And when I wanted to do this for myself, most answers on how to deal with `multipart/form-data` requests using the `requests` library entail using the `files` parameter, which, due to complicated reasons, will be very hard to use. This is why I am wondering if there is a way to do this only using the `data` parameter.

### The Actual Problem

I have not been able to send

```
--1586499478979
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="content"

Hello, World!
--1586499478979
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="tts"

false
--1586499478979--
```

With the headers

```
{
  "Authorization": "Bot <token>",
  "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=--1586499478979",
  "Accept": "*/*"
}
```

To `https://discord.com/api/channels/<channel_id>/messages`

When attempting to do what is above I consistently receive a `400` error, with the data sent back stating `{"message": "Cannot send an empty message", "code": 50006}`.

### What I have tried

I have tried to take the advice of other threads and remove `Content-Type` so the browser or library (depends on who was stating the answer, I don't really know the correct one) determines the type for you

I have also attempted to replace all instances of `\n` with `\r\n` in accordance to the [specifications of multipart/form-data](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7578#section-4), but it did not work.

I have also directly copying the first example provided by Discord with no modifications above to no avail.

After more trying I have found that the `files` parameter does achieve what I am wanting, at the cost of a lot of complication down the line. I will be using it as a hacky fix until I can get a proper one sorted.

### What I have

Currently, I am running the line

```py
requests.post("https://discord.com/api/channels/<channel_id>/messages", data=content, headers={"Authorization": "Bot <token>", "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=--1586499478979", "Accept": "*/*"})
```

To test what I have, `content` here is set to the data I have shown above.

Thank you so much for reading, all answers are appreciated!

Comment: add content-lenght to the header

Comment: @SiddharthChabra I am now using:
`requests.post("https://discord.com/api/channels/<channel_id>/messages", data=content, headers={"Authorization": "Bot <token>", "Content-Length": str(len(content)), "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=--1586499478979", "Accept": "*/*"})`
And it still has the same error

Comment: try using https://pypi.org/project/discord.py/ its a pretty decent wrapper used for writing bots

Comment: I ended up biting the bullet and using the multipart writer in `aiohttp`, the reason why I can't use `discord.py` is that I am writing my own discord wrapper in a python-based language.

Comment: you could see the implementation of discord.py for multipart and see where you are going wrong.

Comment: Yeah, in the end I did get it working but had to change up the language to get it to work, that's why I checked to see if I could do it with plain requests first, because that would have saved time but oh well, in the end it works.